# System of three charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, vectors

> Two charges $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are located at points with position vectors $\textbf r_{1}$ and $\textbf r_{2}$ respectively. A third charge $q_{3}$ is to be placed at a position $\textbf r_{3}$ such that the system of three charges remains in equilibrium. Is it necessary for $q_{1},q_{2},q_{3}$ to be collinear?

My attempt and assumptions:

Firstly, if any of the three charges has an unbalanced force, the system is then not in equilibrium. So, let us look at the equilibrium condition for charge $q_{3}$.

Case 1: $q_{1},q_{2}$ have opposite polarities.

(a) $|q_{1}|=|q_{2}|$

We have,

It seems to me the polarity of $q_{3}$ is irrelevant. It only flips the direction in the electric field lines generated by $q_{1},q_{2}$
$$\textbf E(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{o}}\left(\frac{2p\cos\theta}{r^3}\textbf e_{r}+\frac{p\sin\theta}{r^3}\textbf e_{\theta}\right)$$
(Here, $p$ is the dipole moment)

For $\textbf E(r,\theta)=\textbf 0$
The radial and transverse components must be independently be $0$. This is impossible as there is no value of $\theta$ for which $\sin$ and $\cos$ are simultaneously $0$ since $p$ cannot be $0$.

(b) $q_{1}\neq q_{2}$

I assume this only makes the field stronger with respect to the charge having higher magnitude. (I assume it to make the field lines more sharper with respect to the charge with higher magnitude), and should overall not generate an equilibrium point.

Since in case 1, $q_{3}$ itself is not in equilibrium, we cannot even talk about the whole system.

Case 2:$q_{1},q_{2}$ have same polarities.

The electric field lines suggest that the equilibrium point for $q_{3}$ lies somewhere along the line joining and in between $q_{1},q_{2}$, exactly at the midpoint if $|q_{1}|=|q_{2}|$. Along the line but not in between, $q_{3}$ will feel attraction/repulsion depending on it's polarity.

(a)If the polarity of $q_{3}$ is the same as $q_{1},q_{2}$,then, $q_{3}$ will be at equilibrium at some point along the line and in between but simultaneously $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ will be repelled along the same line, in direction away from $q_{3}$. So the polarity of $q_{3}$ cannot be the same as $q_{1},q_{2}$.

(b) If the polarity of $q_{3}$ is different from $q_{1},q_{2}$. This looks like the probable case to produce an equilibrium point.

Conclusion:

$q_{1},q_{2}$ must have same polarity and $q_{3}$ must have different polarity.

Only then, an equilibrium point can be established for $q_{3}$ lying at some point in between the line joining $q_{1},q_{2}$.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/44126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your Conclusion:
>   $q_{1}, q_{2}$ must have same polarity and $q_{3}$ must have different polarity.

is wrong by itself : If the triad of charges $\,\left(q_{1}, q_{2},q_{3}\right)\,$ is in equilibrium if and only if   $\,\lbrace q_{1}\cdot q_{2}>0 \,\land\,  q_{1}\cdot q_{3}<0\rbrace\,$ then the triad  of charges which comes out from 
 their permutation $\,\left(q'_{1}\!=\!q_{1}, q'_{2}\!=\!q_{3},q'_{3}\!=\!q_{2}\right)\,$ is also in equilibrium but violates this rule since $\,\lbrace q'_{1}\cdot q'_{2}\!=\!q_{1}\cdot q_{3}<0 \,\land \, q'_{1}\cdot q'_{3}\!=\!q_{1}\cdot q_{2}>0\rbrace$.

[image]

**Hint :** Without loss of generality fix the charges $\,q_{1}\,$ and $\,q_{2}\,$ on the $\,x-$axis at a given distance $\,d\,$ apart and place the charge $\,q_{3}\,$
on the same axis at coordinate $\,x\,$ to be determined for the system to be in equilibrium.

Try to prove that the coordinate $\,x\,$  must satisfy the equation
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\dfrac{x\!-\!d\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\!-\!d\vert^{3}}}{\dfrac{x\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\vert^{3}}}=-\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}
\tag{Hint-A}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\xi\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert \xi\vert^{3}}=-\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}} \, \quad \text{where} \:\:\xi \equiv \dfrac{x\!-\!d}{x}
\tag{Hint-A$^{\prime}$}
\end{equation}
and the charge $\,q_{3}\,$ the equation
\begin{equation}
q_{3}=-\dfrac{\vert x\vert^{3}}{x\hphantom{^{3}}}\dfrac{q_{2}}{d^{2}}=\dfrac{\vert x\!-\!d\vert^{3}}{x\!-\!d\hphantom{^{3}}}\dfrac{q_{1}}{d^{2}}
\tag{Hint-B}
\end{equation} 
where in (Hint-B)  $\,x\,$ is a solution of  (Hint-A).

---

**EDIT**

We'll use the following symbols :
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{f}_{ji} & =\text{force on charge $\,q_{i}\,$ from charge $\,q_{j}\,$}\, , \quad j\ne i
\tag{symbols-01}\\
\mathbf{F}_{i} & =\sum\limits_{j\ne i} \mathbf{f}_{ji}=\text{resultant force on charge $\,q_{i}$}
\tag{symbols-02}
\end{align}
Obviously the problem is 1-dimensional, for if the three charges don't lie on a line then for the force on charge $\,q_{i}\,$ we would have $\,\mathbf{F}_{i}\ne \boldsymbol{0}\,$ as the resultant of the two non-collinear  forces $\,\mathbf{f}_{ji}\, ,j\ne i\,,$ from the other two charges.

So let the three charges $\,q_{1},q_{2},q_{3}\,$ on the $\,x\!-\!$axis as in Figure 01. For the forces on the three charges we have (note that $\,\mathbf{f}_{ji}=-\mathbf{f}_{ij}$ and $\,x \ne0,d\,$)

\begin{align}
q_{1} : \mathbf{f}_{21} & =-k\dfrac{q_{1}q_{2}}{d^{2}}\, , \quad \mathbf{f}_{31} =-k\dfrac{q_{1}q_{3}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x 
\tag{01a}\\
\mathbf{F}_{1} & =\mathbf{f}_{21}+\mathbf{f}_{31} =-k\dfrac{q_{1}q_{2}}{d^{2}}-k\dfrac{q_{1}q_{3}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x = -kq_{1}\left[\dfrac{q_{2}}{d^{2}}+\dfrac{q_{3}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x \right]
\tag{01b}\\
q_{2} : \mathbf{f}_{12} & =+k\dfrac{q_{2}q_{1}}{d^{2}}\, , \quad \mathbf{f}_{32} =-k\dfrac{q_{2}q_{3}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right) 
\tag{02a}\\
\mathbf{F}_{2} & =\mathbf{f}_{12}+\mathbf{f}_{32} =+k\dfrac{q_{2}q_{1}}{d^{2}}-k\dfrac{q_{2}q_{3}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right)=+k q_{2}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{d^{2}}-\dfrac{q_{3}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right)\right] 
\tag{02b}\\
q_{3} :\mathbf{f}_{13} & =+k\dfrac{q_{3}q_{1}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x \, , \quad \mathbf{f}_{23} =+k\dfrac{q_{3}q_{2}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right) 
\tag{03a}\\
\mathbf{F}_{3} & =\mathbf{f}_{13}+\mathbf{f}_{23} =+k\dfrac{q_{3}q_{1}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x+k\dfrac{q_{3}q_{2}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right) 
=+kq_{3}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{\vert x \vert ^{3}}x+\dfrac{q_{2}}{\vert x\!-\!d \vert ^{3}}\left(x\!-\!d\right)\right] 
\tag{03b}
\end{align}

Note that  as expected (no external forces, zero sum of internal forces)
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{1}\!+\!\mathbf{F}_{2}\!+\!\mathbf{F}_{3}=\boldsymbol{0}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
so if we set
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{1}=\boldsymbol{0}\, , \quad \mathbf{F}_{2}=\boldsymbol{0}
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
then automatically
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{3}=\boldsymbol{0}
\tag{06}
\end{equation}
and the system is in equilibrium.

Now, for (05) to be valid we must have from (02b) and (01b) respectively
\begin{align}
  \dfrac{x\!-\!d\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\!-\!d\vert^{3}} & =\hphantom{-}\dfrac{1}{d^{2}}\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{3}}
\tag{07a}\\
\dfrac{x\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\vert^{3}} \hphantom{\:\:\;} & =-\dfrac{1}{d^{2}}\dfrac{q_{2}}{q_{3}}
\tag{07b}
\end{align}
Dividing equations (07) yields
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\dfrac{x\!-\!d\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\!-\!d\vert^{3}}}{\dfrac{x\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert x\vert^{3}}}=-\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}
\tag{08}
\end{equation}
that is the hint equation (Hint-A), or
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\xi\hphantom{^{3}}}{\vert \xi\vert^{3}}=-\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}} \, \quad \text{where} \:\:\xi \equiv \dfrac{x\!-\!d}{x}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
that is the hint equation (Hint-A$^{\prime}$).

We note that equation (08) is independent of the value of the charge $\,q_{3}$. This might be expected, since its solution with respect to  $\,x\,$ give us the point where the resultant electrostatic field of charges $\,q_{1},q_{2}\,$ is zero. In other words, on this point $\,\mathbf{F}_{3}= \boldsymbol{0}\,$, see equation (03b).

To the contrary, for the forces $\,\mathbf{F}_{1},\mathbf{F}_{2}\,$ to be both zero the value of $\,q_{3\,}$ must satisfy the equation
\begin{equation}
\bbox[#FFFF88,5px,border:1px solid black]{
-\dfrac{\vert x\vert^{3}}{x\hphantom{^{3}}}\dfrac{q_{2}}{d^{2}}=q_{3}=\dfrac{\vert x\!-\!d\vert^{3}}{x\!-\!d\hphantom{^{3}}}\dfrac{q_{1}}{d^{2}}}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
that is the hint equation (Hint-B).

Note that equation (10), since it includes equation (08), is sufficient to give us the values of $\,x,q_{3}\,$ in order to have system equilibrium.

From (09) we have
\begin{equation}
\vert \xi\vert^{2}=\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert} \hphantom{\:\:} \Longrightarrow \hphantom{\:\:} \xi=\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert}}\hphantom{\:\:}  \Longrightarrow \hphantom{\:\:} \dfrac{x\!-\!d}{x}=\text{sign}\left(\xi\right)\sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2} \vert}{\vert q_{1} \vert}}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\text{sign}\left[\xi\right]\equiv \text{sign of $\,\xi\,$}\stackrel{\text{(09)}}{=\!\!=\!\!=}\text{sign}\left[\!-\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]=-\text{sign}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]
\tag{12}
\end{equation}
and so (11) yields
\begin{equation}
\left(\!1\!+\!\text{sign}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]\sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert}}\:\right)x = d
\tag{13}
\end{equation}
Equation (13) has the solution 
\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{d}{\left(\!1\!+\!\text{sign}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]\sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert}}\:\right)} \qquad  \textbf{if} \qquad \left(\!1\!+\!\text{sign}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]\sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert}}\:\right)\ne 0
\tag{14}
\end{equation}
while **the problem is impossible** if
\begin{equation}
1\!+\!\text{sign}\left[\dfrac{q_{1}}{q_{2}}\right]\sqrt{\dfrac{\vert q_{2}\vert}{\vert q_{1}\vert}}=0
\tag{15}
\end{equation}
Above equation is valid if and only if $\,q_{2}=-q_{1}\,$ so we have as a first case : 
\begin{equation}
\bbox[#FFFFF0,5px,border:1px solid black]{
\textbf{CASE A :} \qquad q_{2}=-q_{1} \:\:\:\Longrightarrow \:\:\:\text{problem impossible}}
\tag{16}
\end{equation}
Now let proceed to other CASES. Suppose that the two charges are both positive or both negative, that is $\,q_{1}q_{2}>0\,$. Then from (14) 
\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\,d
\tag{17}
\end{equation}
and from (10)
\begin{equation}
-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}q_{2}=q_{3}=-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}q_{1}
\tag{18}
\end{equation}
Note that the charge $\,q_{3}\,$ must be placed between the two charges $\,q_{1},q_{2}\,$ having charge opposite to the common charge of them.

So
\begin{equation}
\bbox[#FFFFF0,5px,border:1px solid black]{
\textbf{CASE B :} \quad q_{1}q_{2}>0 \Longrightarrow  
\begin{cases}
x\hphantom{_{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\,d  \\
\\
q_{3}=-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}q_{2}=-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!+\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}q_{1}
\end{cases}}
\tag{19}
\end{equation}
see also Figure 02 at the end<sup>(1)</sup>.

For the next CASE C suppose that $\,q_{1}q_{2}<0\,$, that is one is positive and the other negative. To exclude the CASE A, see equation (16), we further assume $\,q_{2}\ne -q_{1}$. Then from (14) 
\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\,d
\tag{20}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{align}
\text{If} \:\vert q_{1} \vert > \vert q_{2} \vert &  \Longrightarrow  x>\hphantom{\!\!-}d>0 \stackrel{\text{(10)}}{ \Longrightarrow } q_{3}=-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{2}=+\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{1}
\tag{21a}\\
\text{If} \:\vert q_{1} \vert < \vert q_{2} \vert &  \Longrightarrow  x<\!\!-d<0 \stackrel{\text{(10)}}{ \Longrightarrow } q_{3}=+\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{2}=-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{1}
\tag{21b}
\end{align}
So CASE C could be summarized as follows

\begin{equation}
\bbox[#FFFFF0,5px,border:1px solid black]{
\textbf{CASE C :} \quad 
\begin{vmatrix}
q_{1}q_{2}<0 \\
q_{2}\ne -q_{1}
\end{vmatrix}
\Longrightarrow  
\begin{cases}
x\hphantom{_{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\,d  \\
\\
q_{3}=
\begin{cases}
-\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{2}\quad \text{if} \quad \vert q_{1} \vert > \vert q_{2} \vert \\
+\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert q_{1} \vert}\!-\!\sqrt{\vert q_{2} \vert}}\right)^{\!\!\!2}\!q_{2}\quad \text{if} \quad \vert q_{1} \vert < \vert q_{2} \vert
\end{cases}
\end{cases}}
\tag{22}
\end{equation}

---

<sup>(1)
In the Figures below the charges are shown as vertical vectors parallel to the $y-$axis. The positives towards the $+y$ in red color, the negatives towards the $-y$ in blue color.</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this is amazing! Thanks for the help. I understood it now!