# Equilibrium position of $ n $ free charges as polynomials roots

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, equilibrium

The classic problem of the electrostatic equilibrium positions of a linear system of $ n $ free unit charges between two fixed charges is well known, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/350628/) an example with $n = 1$.

Few days ago I found out a nice result going back to Stieltjes and Hasse: if the potential between the two fixed charges is logarithmic, then the positions mentioned above can be computed as the roots of the Jacobi polynomial $P_{n}^{(2p-1,2q-1)}$, where $p$ is the fixed charge positioned in position $-1$,
$q$ is  is the fixed charge in position $+1$ and $n$ is the number of free unit charges (I attached an extract from Szego's book "Orthogonal polynomials").

My question is if there exist anything similar for the Coulomb potential  $V=1/r$. I found some reference at the end of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(98)00156-3), but I would know more.

[image]

Comment: The "Coulomb potential" is 1/r in three dimensions, logarithmic in two dimensions and constant in one dimension (there is "nowhere for the field lines to go" in a one dimensional problem). Is this supposed to be a "charged beads on a string in 2d" problem? The physical interpretation in that case is more like "charged sliding parallel wires in 3d", I believe. I have no intuition about the solution. It might very well be the zeros of a polynomial. The solution for point charges can certainly be written as zeros of a function, but will it be a polynomial? Is that the question?

Comment: @FlatterMann well the question is about the possibility of finding the electrostatic equilibrium position of a linear system  of n unit charges constrained on a line in an inversely proportional potential

Comment: I don't think there is much of a doubt that such a solution exists and it can certainly be written as the zeros of a function. It can even be written as the zeros of a polynomial with real coefficients (that's a trivial statement in mathematics). The only question might be if it can be written as the zeros of a polynomial with e.g. integer or fractional coefficients. That I don't know.